# How would I use this GitHub repo in my C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, github

Here is the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Cirx08/TapoSharp).

And I have a very barebones project, all it does is type "Hello World in the console, how would I reference this GitHub project and use the code under "Scanning for devices"?

Thank you.

Tried packing the project into a DLL, but it returned:
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ScanForDevices' does not exist in the namespace 'TapoSharp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use TapoSharp as NuGet package: just do Manage NuGet packages and Browse for TapoSharp.
Here it is in Nuget.org:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TapoSharp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
**TapoSharp.Scanner scanner = new TapoSharp.Scanner();
scanner.ScanForDevices();**

I think it can resolve CS0234 , you can do the rest.